# Selenium 2.53 : csv files not downloading automatically using the new Marionette Firefox driver

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver, firefox-marionette

I have a automation requirement where after a certain step a csv file needs to be downloaded and saved into a folder. In order to achieve the same ,The Firefox driver has been setup as below.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
try
    {
            profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
    }
catch
    {
    }
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", Config.I.TempDirectory);
    profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
    profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv");
```

After profile has been set with required preferences. The  Firefox driver was initialized as required for using the new  Marionette driver

```
public static RemoteWebDriver GetFirefoxDriver(FirefoxProfile profile = null)
    {
        FirefoxDriverService firefoxService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();

        // this should be moved to a config file.
        firefoxService.FirefoxBinaryPath = Config.I.FirefoxBinaryPath;

        if (profile == null)
        {
            var firefoxOptions = new FirefoxProfileOptions() { IsMarionette = true };
            return new FirefoxDriver(firefoxService, firefoxOptions, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        }
        else
        {
            var firefoxOption = new FirefoxProfileOptions(profile) { IsMarionette = true };
            var driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxService, firefoxOption, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            return driver;
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Extending the firefox options, so that both profile and service can be set for driver at the time of initialization,
    /// Need to check whether the same needs to be here or not.
    /// </summary>
    public class FirefoxProfileOptions : FirefoxOptions
    {
        private DesiredCapabilities _capabilities;

        public FirefoxProfileOptions()
            : base()
        {
            _capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
            _capabilities.SetCapability("marionette", this.IsMarionette);
        }

        public FirefoxProfileOptions(FirefoxProfile profile)
            : this()
        {
            _capabilities.SetCapability(FirefoxDriver.ProfileCapabilityName, profile.ToBase64String());
        }

        public override void AddAdditionalCapability(string capabilityName, object capabilityValue)
        {
            _capabilities.SetCapability(capabilityName, capabilityValue);
        }
    }
```

The code was working properly before we upgraded to selenium 2.53.1 and Firefox 48. Any suggestions or pointers in the right direction would be of great help.